# Printing to Label Printer using Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have been working on a macro that needs to print to a label printer instead of the network printer. No matter what I try, it refuses to switch from the default printer to the label printer.

Please take a look at the following code and let me know if you see anything wrong:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim Box As String
Box = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to print this label " _
& "?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
If Box = vbNo Then
Exit Sub
Else: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Label").PrintOut ActivePrinter:="MSP-Label2 on msp-dc-001"
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but `Box` should be declared as either an `Integer` or (better) `VbMsgBoxResult`.  `MsgBox` doesn't return a `String`.

Comment: I just tried many different combinations of VbMsgBoxResult and could not get it to work. Can you please write out the entire line of code?

Comment: `Dim Box As VbMsgBoxResult`

Comment: I get a Compile Error: User-defined type not defined.

Comment: What happens if you set the printer as the default printer in windows? Do you have drivers installed to the printer? Mostly due to IT restrictions, I gave up trying to print on lable printer from Excel on my company computer and bought "sticky" normal paper. Just thought you should know there is paper that can be loaded in normal printers with a sticky backside

Comment: Huh. That's odd - it's a member of the `Visual Basic For Applications" library - if that isn't loaded, nothing's going to work...

Comment: Also, it's not that easy to switch printer in Excel. I'm not at work now so I can't see the code I use to switch to PDF creator. But after googling I found [this](http://pixcels.nl/set-activeprinter-excel/). I can't say I recognize the code but the text is and issues explained is something I recognize

Comment: Do you have any broken references? `Tools->References...` - they'll have "MISSING" in front of them.

Comment: @Andreas - when I manually change the printer to the label printer, every works.
I also found that page and tried using it, but it did not work for me.

Comment: @Comintern - There are hundreds of references listed, none of them have "MISSING" including the Visual Basic for Applications.

Comment: So changing printer manually works as expected. Let me think on this tomorrow, I'm in bed now

Comment: Something is definitely wrong then - Try declaring it as `Dim Box As VBA.VbMsgBoxResult`. If that still gives you the compile error you might want to rebuild the workbook.

Comment: Is it possible to post pictures here?

Comment: You can edit them into the question. If they don't render correctly, somebody here will fix them for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try letting your user select a printer, see if this works:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim box As String
box = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to print this label?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

If box = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show = False Then Exit Sub
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Label").PrintOut Copies:=1
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked, and that brought up a window and showed the printer as: \\msp-dc-001\MSP-Label2
When using [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1021932-changing-active-printer-macro.html)
that brings up a box with \\msp-dc-001\MSP-Label2 on Ne07:

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured it out!
The following code worked:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Box As String
Box = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to print this label " _
& "?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
If Box = vbNo Then
Exit Sub
Else: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Label").PrintOut ActivePrinter:="\\msp-dc-001\MSP-Label2 on Ne07"
End If
End Sub
```